# Django in difference OS (windows10 &Ubuntu16.04) access same DB (SQL Server 2012) but show difference result to template

Tags: python, django, windows, ubuntu, sql-server-2012

Django version: 1.11.2
Python version: 3.6

I have a problem when I use Django to show data from database.

I had 20 articles in database (table: ResultArticle)

In Windows 10, I can show all article (20) to template (web).
But in Ubuntu 16.04, I just can show 18 to template.

I loss 2 article, this 2 article had long content(full_text 12728 bytes & full_text_stem 11471 bytes  )

I doubt some kind of problems about buffer size (per object)
Maybe Django had limitation of buffer size.
I spent one day finding how to change it.

models.py

```
class ResultArticle(models.Model):
    article_guid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)
    project_guid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    full_text = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.
    full_text_stem = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    resource = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    get_time = models.DateTimeField()
    url = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'result_article'
```

views.py

```
def archives(request,project_id,filter): 
    articles = ResultArticle.objects.filter(project_guid = project_id)
    return render(request, 'archives/archives.html', {'articles': articles})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you sure you're connecting to the exact same database each time?

Comment: I connect same database and same table.  
And all code is same,just OS difference.  
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any point of getting less number of rows from same database and same table using same query. Please make sure you're using and configuring(in Django) the exact same database in both OS. Also check if you really have 20 rows in table in both OS.

Comment: I count articles (ResultArticle object)  in view.  
Both OS return 20 rows.   Then I print articles (ResultArticle object) content,it just return 18 object in ubuntu.